# MySQL query difficulty

Tags: mysql, select

I would like your help with the following:

### query 1:

```
SELECT stock.ST_CODE as xCODE, (sum(ordercont.QTY) / 12) as x12WeeksAvg
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN ordercont ON ordercont.O_REF = orders.O_REF
LEFT JOIN stock ON stock.PD_CODE = ordercont.PD_CODE
WHERE stock.ST_CODE IS NOT NULL
  AND orders.O_CUSTDATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB( (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)) , INTERVAL 84 DAY)
  AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)
GROUP BY stock.ST_CODE
```

### query 2:

```
SELECT stock.ST_CODE as xCODE, (sum(ordercont.QTY) / 4) as x4WeeksAvg
FROM orders LEFT JOIN ordercont ON ordercont.O_REF = orders.O_REF
LEFT JOIN stock ON stock.PD_CODE = ordercont.PD_CODE
WHERE stock.ST_CODE IS NOT NULL
  AND orders.O_CUSTDATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB( (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)) , INTERVAL 28 DAY)
  AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)
GROUP BY stock.ST_CODE
```

Is there any way to have the result like this (the queries returns different number of results):

```
------------------------------------
| xCode | x12WeeksAvg | x4WeeksAvg |
------------------------------------
|  ...  |     ...     |    ...     |
------------------------------------
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the BETWEEN condition

```
orders.O_CUSTDATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB( (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)) , INTERVAL 84 DAY) 
                      AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)
```

into two parts

```
AND orders.O_CUSTDATE >= DATE_SUB( (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)) , INTERVAL 84 DAY) 
AND orders.O_CUSTDATE <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)
```

and rewrite it to

```
AND orders.O_CUSTDATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 84) DAY
AND orders.O_CUSTDATE <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) - 1) DAY
```

to get shorter and more readable code. Do the same for the second query.

Now the two queries differ only in two expressions

```
(sum(ordercont.QTY) / 12) as x12WeeksAvg
(sum(ordercont.QTY) /  4) as x4WeeksAvg

orders.O_CUSTDATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 84) DAY
orders.O_CUSTDATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 28) DAY
```

Given

```
<X>: orders.O_CUSTDATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 84) DAY
```

and

```
<Y>: orders.O_CUSTDATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 28) DAY
```

you can use conditional aggregation to combine the two queries:

```
SELECT stock.ST_CODE as xCODE,
    (sum(CASE WHEN <X> THEN ordercont.QTY ELSE 0 END) / 12) as x12WeeksAvg,
    (sum(CASE WHEN <Y> THEN ordercont.QTY ELSE 0 END) /  4) as x4WeeksAvg
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN ordercont ON ordercont.O_REF = orders.O_REF
LEFT JOIN stock     ON stock.PD_CODE   = ordercont.PD_CODE
WHERE stock.ST_CODE IS NOT NULL
  AND orders.O_CUSTDATE <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) - 1) DAY
GROUP BY stock.ST_CODE
```

Replace `<X>` and `<Y>` accordingly.

**Update**

To improve the performance you can add

```
AND orders.O_CUSTDATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 84) DAY
```

to the WHERE clause.

Also note that the condition `stock.ST_CODE IS NOT NULL` will convert your LEFT JOINs to INNER JOINs. So you could as well just write `JOIN`.

Comment: Really elegant solution, but the speed of execution and fetching is much better with PJ's solution.

Comment: Indeed Paul, now it's getting 30% faster than PJ's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can subquery them like this to get your desired output:

```
SELECT A.xCODE, 
    COALESCE(B.x12WeeksAvg, 'N/A') as x12WeeksAvg, 
    COALESCE(C.x4WeeksAvg, 'N/A') as x4WeeksAvg
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ST_CODE as xCODE FROM stock) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT stock.ST_CODE as xCODE, (sum(ordercont.QTY) / 12) as x12WeeksAvg
    FROM orders
      LEFT JOIN ordercont ON ordercont.O_REF = orders.O_REF
      LEFT JOIN stock ON stock.PD_CODE = ordercont.PD_CODE
    WHERE stock.ST_CODE IS NOT NULL
      AND orders.O_CUSTDATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB( (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)) , INTERVAL 84 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)
    GROUP BY stock.ST_CODE
          ) B ON A.xCODE = B.xCODE
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT stock.ST_CODE as xCODE, (sum(ordercont.QTY) / 4) as x4WeeksAvg
    FROM orders
      LEFT JOIN ordercont ON ordercont.O_REF = orders.O_REF
      LEFT JOIN stock ON stock.PD_CODE = ordercont.PD_CODE
    WHERE stock.ST_CODE IS NOT NULL
      AND orders.O_CUSTDATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB( (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)) , INTERVAL 28 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY)
    GROUP BY stock.ST_CODE
          ) C ON A.xCODE = C.xCODE
WHERE COALESCE(B.x12WeeksAvg, C.x4WeeksAvg) IS NOT NULL
```